# How to execute a method only once, when multiple threads tries to run it simultaneously; however, other threads in queue should wait for this method

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock, race-condition

I have a TCP reconnect method in a winforms application; multiple threads try to send/receive data over TCP. If the connection is lost while sending the data reconnection is called (can be called from multiple threads). However, I don't want to execute the reconnect multiple times.
To achieve this, I'm using the below code- please let me know if this is a good way.
Thanks in advance.

```
    public bool Reconnect(out bool wasLockedByOThers)
    {
        bool reconnected = wasLockedByOThers = false;
        try
        {
             //check if the lock can be acquired immediately 
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(m_ReconnectLock)) 
            {
                // if not, wait until the lock is acquired. If the lock is acquired here it means reconnect just happened so I'll just return without running it again. But the problem is I'll not know if the previous reconnect call resulted in true or false.
                Monitor.Enter(m_ReconnectLock);
                wasLockedByOThers = true;
            }
            else
            {
                reconnected = true; //reconnect logic
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            reconnected = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(m_ReconnectLock);
        }
        return reconnected;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any locking to ensure your tcp writes are atomic? Are you writing with async methods? Personally I would just use a `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure there's only one task writing or reconnecting.

Comment: they are synchronous methods, however reading(polling) and writing data can happen in parallel- if the reader sees a lost connection, it attempts to reconnect; if the writer sees lost connection, attempts to reconnect; can lead to a potential race condition;